# In html, can a style command be dynamically changed by a script?

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to either display a line of data or not depending on the contents of an input field

The contents of an output line are built like the following:

```
document.getElementById("obstacle").innerHTML = o50_oat+'\xB0 C, \xa0\xa0 '+o50_g+' gal';
```

Then a style command is generated like this:

```
if(o50_g == 0.0)
   document.getElementById("obstaclestyle").innerHTML = "display:none";
else
   document.getElementById("obstaclestyle").innerHTML = "";
```

The intent is that when o50_g == 0.0, the following, in the html, causes nothing to be displayed.

```
  <span style=<span id="obstaclestyle"></span>    
  <span style="color:green"><span id="obstacle"></span></span><br><br><br><br><br>
  </span>
```

and when 050_g != 0.0, the above will actually display the line

Instead the above displays:

display:none 0° C,    0 gal,    0 min,    0 sec,    0 ft

with the data in green

I tried various combinations of punctuation for display:none but none of them worked.  They either caused no data to be output or display:none is just seen as text like the above.

Is what I am trying to do possible with the right syntax

Comment: You have HTML in an attribute value; that doesn't work. If you want to set an element's style attribute, use `element.style.display = "none";`